# Frontend Versioning with Grunt and Git

Tags: git, gruntjs, versioning, web-frontend

I have a web app whose frontend assets I'm developing and managing with Grunt. Here's the rough idea of its organization:

```
_app
_fonts
_img
_lib
_scss
_templates
FrontendApplication
Gruntfile.js
```

So I run grunt watch to keep track of my files, then use grunt-copy to copy over the resulting files into the dist/DATE folder, which the server serves. Like:

`FrontendApplication/FrontendApplication/Assets/2014-06`

Inside this folder sits the final static files, like this:

```
app
css
fonts
img
lib
index.html
```

Now, we have different clients who are using this same code base, but with slightly different frontend assets, like the logo image and some new css to override the default one, e.g. companysname.css. As such, we are thinking of publishing customized versions of the app to a different folder for clients, e.g:

`FrontendApplication/FrontendApplication/Assets/CLIENTNAME`

My superior has provided a app.conf that reads like the below:

```
[Domains]
default=2014-06
client1=client1
```

And he's saying we should have Grunt read this file and then determine which folder to publish to. I.e. if client1 is defined, we publish customized assets to the client1/ folder. Otherwise, we fall on the default of 2014-06/. The server will look for the client1/ folder where applicable, and when that's not found, it will point to the default 2014-06/ folder to show the static assets.

So here are my questions:

1. Is it possible for Grunt to read and extract information from a file sitting in the directory then pass them as parameters to the config file to be used by other tasks? How do you go about doing it?
2. If that's possible, how can I maintain different versions of frontend assets based on clients?

The way I see it, this is what can be done:

First, under Git branch *master*, set a variable in gruntfile that points to the destination folder, something like:

```
    var globalConfig = {
//valueWePluckedFromAppConf: '2014-06',
    destinationFolder: 'FrontendApplication/FrontendApplication/Assets/' + valueWePluckedFromAppConf
    };
```

And, under client branch, say *client1*, have the variable point to a separate destination folder. Of course, under this branch, the scss files and images and maybe scripts may vary:

```
var globalConfig = {
//valueWePluckedFromAppConf: 'client1',
destinationFolder: 'FrontendApplication/FrontendApplication/Assets/' + valueWePluckedFromAppConf
};
```

That way, Git will take care of the destination. If under master branch, we will publish to 2014-06/, while when we're on client branch, we switch to client1/. And so on. So Grunt will somehow read the app.conf mentioned above, retrieve the value for the destination folder and then publish there.

Of course, one problem I see is that I need to switch branches in order to access files, and I probably need to switch branches to push both 2014-06/ and client1/ to the server. And when we have a new major version, we will change the app.conf, and Grunt will push to, say, 2015-01/ instead under a new branch/tag.

The above is a very rough and fuzzy solution I came up with based on my superior's request. But frankly, neither him nor myself are familiar with Grunt enough to know how to accomplish the above, and I have personally never worked with versioning frontend assets before (let alone automating the flow), that's why I'm posting this.

Any advice will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: I read that long story and I am confused. What do you really want. For your questions, you can read files using Grunt... But I want to understand for what specifically you are using Grunt. And what is the configuration file you are talking about and when it will be used? (at the time of grunt processing or when user assess the site )

Comment: Hi sorry for the confusion, partly because I wasn't sure of the request and was trying to put things together. The configuration file is to be read at the time of grunt processing so that Grunt knows where to spit out the published files.